# How can I fit a door in a frame that is too small?

Tags: doors, exterior, door-frame

I bought some used French doors to replace a sliding door.  The sliding door measured 96" X 60".  The French doors measure 96" X 60¼".  I made the mistake of not measuring both doors.  I just measured that the first door was < 30" and assumed I was ok.  The other door was an inch bigger.  The frame for the French doors is also thicker than the sliding door, mistake number two.  My question is, what should I do?  The biggest challenge I have is that I need about ½ inch on at least one side and about ½ inch on the top.  Mistake number three was not considering that the doors need to clear the tile when they open inward.  That's why I need about another ½ inch on the top.

Do I need to throw in the towel on the doors or try to re-frame it?  There are two studs on each side.  I don't see any studs above the 2X4 going across the top (I have 10' ceilings). I was considering moving that 2X4 up about an inch and then sawing/prying one of the side studs.  That doesn't seem natural.  I suppose the "right" way to do it would be to remove both studs from one side and then move both of them.  I'm just not certain I can easily do that.

In case you can't tell, I'm not a professional.  Any advice is appreciated.  I'm willing to get new doors, but that's not my preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok Kenny, here is the plan.  You can remove one Jack stud and door header with a sawzall(cutting between the studs to cut the nails) and some work. You can then replace the jack stud with a 3/4" board cut to 3 1/2" width and the new 3/4" higher height.  Put a 3/4" block on top of the remaining jack stud and reinstall the header 2X4. It will still fit between the outside studs and be supported 3/4" higher then before.  Obviously, you will have to trim some drywall away to do this, but that can be pieced in and patched fairly easily and if you're careful cutting it before the demo begins. The drywall seam may be covered by the door trim.  The result will be a finished opening 3/4 inches wider and taller than you started with. Your new door should slide right in!  Good Luck.

Comment: Shirlock, thanks for the plan, it actually sounds better than what I was thinking on my comment to Michael's post.  With a second floor above and jack studs running floor to ceiling, does it change your answer.  We were very close to removing the jack stud yesterday.  Got about half way and then decided to try and shave the backside of the door frame.  That's when we realized the doors still wouldn't clear the tile.

Comment: Implemented this plan this past weekend.  Funny, the easiest part of the whole operation was sawing off the jack stud and replacing with a 1 X 4. The jack stud actually ran to the ceiling, so I didn't need to put the 3/4" block on top.  For a DIY job, I'm pretty happy.  It certainly isn't perfect looking, but functions well.  I'll post some pics soon.