# How can I fit patio French doors in a frame that is too small?

Tags: doors, exterior, door-frame

My question is very similar to ["How can I fit a door in a frame that is too small?"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/how-can-i-fit-a-door-in-a-frame-that-is-too-small) except my house is made of concrete block.  I bought a used patio French door to replace my sliding door. The sliding door measured 71 1/2 x 80. The French doors measured the same. After taking out the frame for the sliders, I need at least 1/2 inch on the top and sides. Help!

Comment: Wait... Is the frame a 1/2" too large, or is the door 1/2" too large? Is it a 1/2" on each side, or 1/4" on each side for a total of 1/2"?

Comment: The opening is too small for the door and frame. 1/4" on both sides. The door is an exterior door so it is made of steel. I believe my only option is to buy new doors :(

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the construction of the door, but if it's a wood door, you should be able to take off 1/4" from the top and bottom without any problem.